# Jasmine require.js maven plugin

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, jasmine

I am trying to configure jasmine maven plugin to load jasmine specifications using require.js.

Below is my maven configuration

```
<plugin>
<groupId>com.github.searls</groupId>
<artifactId>jasmine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.1.0</version>
<configuration>
<specRunnerTemplate>REQUIRE_JS</specRunnerTemplate>
<jsSrcDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/backbone/js</jsSrcDir>
<jsTestSrcDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/javascript/spec</jsTestSrcDir>
<srcDirectoryName>js</srcDirectoryName>
<specDirectoryName>spec</specDirectoryName>
<specIncludes>
<include>*Spec.js</include>
</specIncludes>
<preloadSources>
<source>backbone/js/libs/jquery/jquery.js</source>
<source>backbone/js/libs/require/require.js</source>
<source>backbone/js/libs/underscore/underscore.js</source>
<source>backbone/js/libs/backbone/backbone.js</source>
<source>backbone/js/libs/bootstrap/bootstrap.js</source>
<source>backbone/js/config.js</source>
</preloadSources>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Below is my jasmine specification:

```
define(['models/Specification'], function(Specification) {
describe("Specification", function() {
var specification;
beforeEach(function() {
specification = new Specification();
})
it("thickness set to 4 by default", function () {
expect(specification.thickness).toEqual(4);
});
});
});
```

Below is the javascript file

```
define(["backbone"], function ($, _, Backbone) {
return Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults: {
thickness: 4
}
});
});
```

I get the following error : **TypeError: Cannot call method "extend" of undefined**

Is there anyway to load my require.js config instead of loading them manually ?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: You've got an issue with your require syntax: `define(["backbone"], function ($, _, Backbone) ...` is assigning `backbone` to `$` in your function. You might want to require `jquery` and `underscore` first.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on rjz's post and to further answer the question...Yes, you can load your require.config file and let it load all of your library files/dependencies for you. There's no need to list the files in the plugin's configuration. I wrote a quick post summarizing my experience with jasmine-maven-plugin using Require.js [jasmine+maven+requirejs+coverage](http://pseudobry.com/jasminemavenrequirejscoverage/). I included my pom.xml in my post for reference. Your main.js (or whatever includes your require.config) should just be one of your source files yes? So  should point to your source directory, and thus your require.config gets loaded, and it handles the loading of your dependencies, not jasmine-maven-plugin. Hope my this helps.